# << operator vs. overloaded + operator for strings in C++

Tags: c++, performance, operators

Is there is difference between the two following lines of code?

(Perhaps in efficiency or something of that nature?)

```
const std::string a = "a";
const std::string b = "b";

std::cout << a << " comes before " << b << "\n";
std::cout << a + " comes before " + b + "\n";
```

Comment: I'd gues it's compiler dependent, but the first one would simply be the equivalent of `output a; output string; output b; output string` and the second is `create string a, concatenate a string, concatenate var b, concatenate string, output completed string`

Comment: Yes.  There is a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes:

The first line calls `operator<<` of `std::cout` (of type `std::ostream`). It prints each of its operands.

The second line calls `operator+` of `std::string`, which creates multiple temporary `std::string` objects which then eventually call `operator<<` which prints them.

Prefer the first because it avoids temporary objects, and works better. Consider the situation were `a` and `b` have type `int`. The first version continues to work the second will no longer work.